# How to execute button if "view" true?

Tags: javascript, webview, lotus-notes

I have a frameset with two link view and both will be displayed same button which I create "CLOSE" button. My view are DRAFT and COMPUTER. My current close button action will open COMPUTER view

Below here my current close button.

```
window.open("http://Internet/name/spec.nsf/$$ViewTemplate%20for%20computer?OpenForm","_self")
```

So what I want to do, when "CLOSE" button is clicked in COMPUTER view it will open COMPUTER view. While in DRAFT view, it will open to DRAFT view. Right now I only can open one view only.

How to make it open view when it on its own view. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I just create two button and set each button for each url. For example:

Close button for DRAFT

```
window.location.href = "http://Internet/new/spec.nsf/$$ViewTemplate%20for%20Draft?OpenForm";
```

Close button for COMPUTER

```
window.location.href = "Internet/new/pcspec.nsf/$$ViewTemplate%20for%20viewmst?OpenForm";
```